# C++ multiple inheritance - same method names - can I somehow remove one of them?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have this structures in C++11

```
struct A {
   int idA;   
   void setId(int i) { idA = i;}
   int getId() { return idA;}

   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B {
   int idB;   
   void setId(int i) { idB = i;}
   int getId() { return idB;}

   virtual void foo2() = 0;
};

struct AB : public A, public B
{
   void foo() override {}
   void foo2() override {}
};
```

Now in main I can call it like this:

```
AB * ab = new AB();
ab->B::setId(10);
```

but I dont really like it.

Is there any other solution?  Methods `setId/getId` from `struct A` are not needed in `AB`. I just did the inheritance, because I need `foo()` and other stuff from `A`, but all other methods are unique.

Comment: Can you modify your hierarchy? E.g. change `A` and introduce extra classes

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I can (in a limited way)

Comment: When you say you "need" `foo()` and other stuff from `A`, do you refer to declarations or definitions?

Comment: It's possible to break up Class A into something else.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you said that you don't need `A`'s version of those methods, you could write

```
struct AB : public A, public B
{
    void foo() override {}
    void foo2() override {}

    using B::setId;
    using B::getId;
};
```

This will put `B`'s implementation of those methods into `AB`'s namespace and make calling them unambiguous.

Comment: A problem with this approach can be that `A::setId` will still get called in this case: `A* ab = new AB(); ab->setId(0);`

Answer (score 9):

What about wrapper forwarding methods:

```
struct AB : public A, public B
{
public:
    void setAId(int i) { A::setID(i); }
    void setBId(int i) { B::setID(i); }
};
```

That way you do not become "victim" of name hiding, your intent becomes clear in the code and you have the names that reflect what they do and you do not need to access the member(s) of base class(es) explicitely.

Alternatively you can create another base class and inherit it virtually in both `A` and `B` in which you would contain the `setId` method.

Comment: This will work, but someone can still call setId() and get the error.

Comment: @MartinPerry Then it should be protected in the base classes imo.

Comment: @Ressurection It will be incorrect, because other classes are inheriting only from A or only from B and they are alowed to call those methods

Comment: @MartinPerry If you have public methods you do not want in your inheritance then you should do composition or split the base class in what you actually want to inherit and the rest. That way both scenarios would work. Name hiding really should not be used for this.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer does work as long as you call `setId(int)` on an object of type AB or an AB pointer (most cases, surely). But if you want to call the function on `A* ab = new AB();` you have to explicitly override it.

```cpp
struct A {
   int idA;   
   virtual void setId(int i) { idA = i;}
};

struct B {
   int idB;   
   virtual void setId(int i) { idB = i;}
};

struct AB : public A, public B
{
    void setId(int i) override { B::setId(i); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that both mine and the accepted answers introduces rather annoying problem, consider:

```
AB ab;
A *a = &ab;
a->setId(10); //problem
a->foo(); //calls AB::foo() correctly
```

When the name hiding is used (accepted answer) the `AB` object never gets called while my answer (wrapping the call) does not account for this either. The correct approach in this case in my opinion is to use `private` inehritance of `A` and exposing only `foo()`, so only one thing would change from original OP's code:

```
struct AB : private A, public B
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically with OO and Inheritance, if functionality reuse is unknown at the time, it is typically better to implement the function several times until you determine a pattern that will allow you to break it apart.

For instance, there is nothing wrong with having a class object being a container of data and inherriting from it.

```
class IdentificationData {
    int ID;
    . . .
}
```

You also do not necessarily need to have functions be part of a class. A class is simply a container, and is used to organize and encapsulate data, functions that may operate on the data, or a collection of functions into one common set.

```
class IdentificationFunctionality{
     static SetID( IdentificationData* obj) {...}
}
```

Doing this will then allow you to do something like...

```
class AB: IdentificationData, B {
    . . .
}

AB* ab = new AB();
IdentificationFunctionality::SetID(&ab);
```

The other benefits to this, is this will allow you to do some book keeping without your objects needing to know the details of the data-banking system.